# Constraints to keep two variable-width views close together at the center of the superview

Tags: ios, cocoa, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have two views side-by-side horizontally in a container view. They are 8 points apart, but have variable widths. I want to keep the center of the two views equal to the center of the container view, so that no matter the size of the container, the two views together are at in the center of the screen.

My idea to achieve this is to create two horizontal constraints, one from the left edge of the container to the left edge of the first object, and the right edge of the second object to the right edge of the container. I would then make these two constraints equal to each other, but variable with the size of the container. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to do this. I can only figure out how to make constraints equal or greater/less than a particular value. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What kind of views are they? Labels? Complex views containing other views?

Comment: They are basic UIViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this in IB.

Create an empty view with width 1 and set a horizontal constraint to position it in the center of your container. This is a placeholder.

Set constraints on your two views relative to this center placeholder view:

Left view should have trailing constraint to the placeholder leading edge.

Right view should have leading constraint to the placeholder trailing edge.

Adjust the constants for these two constraints to achieve the spacing you want between the left and right views.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking extemporaneously, did you try giving the left view a leading constraint to its superviee, giving the right view a trailing constraint and then giving the two a horizontal spacing constraint and an equal width constraint?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like this:

```
[   <-  equal  -> <-  equal  ->   ]
[         [view1] [biggerview2]   ]-- resizable superview, fixed-width views
```

with 8px between the views, then:

```
view1.trailing = superview.centerX - 4
biggerview2.leading = superview.centerX + 4
```

and other obvious constraints like:

```
view1.leading >= default
view1.width > 0

superview.trailing >= biggerview2.trailing + default
biggerview2.width > 0

...
```

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but is there any way to do this in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0):

Just embed your two views into a container view. Set the constraints so that the container closely hugs the two views. Then, center the container view in its superview.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way:
You have superview, and 2 subviews in it (which you want to make 50:50 to superview width):
You need connect width constraint (equal width) from subview to superview, and change multiplier of this constraint from 1 to 0.5 (you can also use syntax 1:2 (or 1:3 for 3 subviews)).
Also you can set constant value there to set padding:

Here is example:

subviews have 2:1 proportional width to superview, and 32 is constant for padding (16 from each side)

So it calculated like (for iPhone 4S screen) (320 width - 32 constant) / 2 = subview width

[image]

You can also do the same with 3, 4, 5 subviews to make more complex views.
Here is link with my another example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48223929/AutolayoutExampleView.xib